# Onejar and resource loading

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-resources-plugin, onejar

I have a maven project which I would like to package in an executable jar.
It's using quite a few dependencies, like spring and so on. 
It was suggested in a few posts to use OneJar, to avoid a lot of headaches.
This is what I have currently in my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.cool.project.Application</mainClass>
                        <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                        <classifier>coolproject</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In my Spring configuration one of the classes needs to pass the a resource (`src/main/resources/coolfile.bin`) path to an external library (jsch) method:

```
String resource = ConfigurationClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("coolfile.bin").getFile();
jsch.addIdentity(resource);
```

When I run `Application.java` from the IDE (eclipse), the entire application loads successfully.

Although when I run `mvn clean install`, the onejar jar is built under the `target` folder, but when I try to run it with `java -jar coolproject.one-jar.jar` the following error is displayed:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/target/coolproject.one-jar.jar!/main/coolproject.jar!/coolfile.bin (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:83
```

If I inspect `coolproject.one-jar.jar`, I can find the `coolproject.jar` under the `main` folder, and if I inspect that, I can see `coolfile.bin` in its root.

So in theory the resource should be found? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `FileInputStream` would not find the path specified by `resource`.
Luckily `jsch` provides another method where you can pass the byte array of the file rather than its location:

```
jsch.addIdentity("coolfile.bin", toByteArray(ConfigurationClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/coolfile.bin")), null, null);
```